# Matchmaking system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, multiplayer, server, matchmaking

I was wondering, how would one go about making a matchmaking system in Unity? I've tried some ideas with the Master Server, but it wasn't doing its job right, since thats a lobby based solution. I have a dedicated server of my own, so hosting myself is no problem.

I was simply just wondering, how and where to begin with this? I'm not asking for a "Complete solution" neither a package from the Unity Assetstore. Simply just an idea of how to start out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about a matchmaking system akin to those found in many multiplayer games, that attempts to pair you up with a player of a similar level of skill to your own.

I would start by looking to my favorite web development environment. You will need to create some sort of web interface that you can connect to using Unity. Typically, the easiest way to do this is using simple HTTP requests via the [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) class.
In order for matchmaking to work, you will need to be able to identify the user, so you need some sort of authentication system, be it one where the user logs in to play, or one that stores some sort of ID on his machine -- but authentication is a whole other topic in itself.

So now you have a server that can identify the player, and a database with information about all the players. This is the point where you need to decide on a matchmaking algorithm. A few of these algorithms exist, but most games use the [Elo system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), typically slightly modified to better fit the game. Alternatives include [Microsoft's TrueSkill](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/) and [Mark Glickman's Glicko](http://www.glicko.net/glicko.html) system.